# complementary function of complex argument in matlab

Tags: matlab, nan

I want to use a bit modified complementary function of complex argument. I defined it by myself because MATLAB can't work straight with complex arguments.

```
w=@(p) exp(-p.^2).*double(erfc(sym(-i*p)));
```

It works, but not for all arguments. In my loops I started to get such vague values as

> NaN +    NaNi

For example for argument `-27.4525 +0.0070*i`.

What does it mean and how to handle it?

Comment: "matlab can't work straight with complex arguments". Yes, yes it can

Comment: show me how. I'm getting error that argument must be real

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the significance of erfc for complex arguments, however, the problem is that erfc goes to infinity:

```
>> syms p real
>> limit(erfc(p*i),p,Inf)

ans =

1 - Inf*i
```

You are multiplying erfc with `exp(-p.^2)` which is 0 hence `Inf*0=NaN`.

It works if you treat the whole thing symbolically and only convert the product to a numeric value, like this:

```
>> w=@(p) double(exp(-sym(p).^2).*erfc(sym(-i*p)));
>> w(-27.4525 +0.0070*i)

ans =

0.0000 - 0.0206*i
```

Comment: Thanks. You helped me a lot.